# Using a Custom Domain Name for a Production org (not for Sites or Experience Cloud)

Tags: custom-domain

The Salesforce documentation (linked below) indicates that you can use an FQDN, like mydomainname.com, to point to your Salesforce production org.  After having a little trouble setting this up, I contacted Salesforce Support and was told that this is only possible for Experience Cloud Sites.  I always thought that was true as well, but the documentation only mentions Experience Cloud in saying that the CDN can only be used for Sites.

Has anyone set up a custom domain name for accessing a Salesforce production org, and, if so, can you explain how you've done it?

Referenced documentation:

[Adding a Domain](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.domain_mgmt_add.htm&type=5)

[Options for Serving a Custom Domain](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.domain_mgmt_domain_config_options.htm&type=5)

Thanks!

Comment: On the "options for serving" page, step 4 for each of the options does say, "content that Salesforce is hosting for you in Salesforce sites or Experience Cloud sites," so I have a feeling the answer is "no" to this one.

Comment: AFAIK custom domain for "baseline" org was never an option. When custom domains were introduced in 2012 or so, it required a site (at the time - a Force.com site).

Comment: Thanks, @identigral -- that's what I thought as well, but seeing this page of the documentation not explicitly related to Experience Cloud had me questioning that.  It's quite vague.  https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.domain_mgmt_add.htm&type=5

Comment: ...though it referencing a siteforce domain should have been a give-away.  Hmm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom domain for base orgs (and its sandboxes) is not possible in Salesforce platform (*at the least there is no documentation around this or OOB approach*). You can only configure subdomains via My Domain ([ref](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.domain_name_overview.htm&type=5))

Consider the following (just my thoughts on why this isn't facilitated yet):

1. As opposed to the base orgs, experience sites are lightweight, support heavy UX customization and actually meant for exposing web content to external users. Since, this perfectly falls under the use case of Salesforce customers wanting to serve their content via experience sites from their existing domains (or new custom domain), Salesforce has an implementation approach and necessary infrastructure in place to support the same.
2. As mentioned [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.domain_name_setup.htm&type=5), there are many domains involved in base org (as opposed to experience cloud site)

> In each Salesforce org, multiple domains serve content to users. In
> addition to your My Domain login URL, your org has application URLs on
> different domains. Here are a few examples.
>
> Lightning pages, Visualforce pages, Experience Cloud sites, Experience Builder for Digital Experiences, Salesforce Sites User-stored content served by Salesforce, such as images and files
>
> When you rename your My Domain or change your My Domain suffix, all those domains are updated.

3. Salesforce is hosted in a multi-tenant infrastructure whose base domain, FQDN, CNAME and related DNS mappings have to follow a certain standard practice and security measures in place.

so, if the base org has to be exposed via custom domain, it would take a lot more than a simple CNAME change or DNS mapping. While this is technically possible, it would be a highly complex soluion and I don't think Salesforce (*has planned or*) has the strategy, infrastructure and necessary solutions in place yet.

Comment: Yep, looking again at step 4 in each of these examples, it does say, "Content that Salesforce is hosting for you in Salesforce sites or Experience Cloud sites."  Salesforce support confirmed.  Thanks, @Arut!

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&type=5&id=sf.domain_mgmt_domain_config_options.htm

Comment: @ShaneSteinfeld Updated my answer with few more supporting points.

Comment: Thanks, @arut!  Appreciate the extra detail.

Answer (score 0):

If you are buying Government Cloud, it might have been possible to change to some different suffix https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000390226&type=1

but still the domain would be something like client.my.salesforce.gov or client.my.salesforce.inc but not like client.com